# IText can't add existing image from storage to PDF

Tags: android, itext, pdf-generation, android-bitmap

I'm creating an appication that needs to create a PDF from different values. Everything is fine except when I try to add images from my external storage to my pdf.

I can access said images, and preview them in the debugger but, nonetheless, I can't figure out how to add them.

On the other hand, I can add an image that come from my assets folder.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
    PdfPTable photosTable = new PdfPTable(3);
    photosTable.setWidths(new float[]{33, 34, 33});

    File picFile = new File(imagePath);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //I know the creation of the file object is redundant but it's the remains from older code
    Bitmap pix = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picFile.getPath());
    pix.compress(JPEG, 100, baos);

    Image pic = Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
    PdfPCell picCell = new PdfPCell(pic, true);
    picCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    photosTable.addCell(picCell);

    pdf.add(photosTable);
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? I can access and preview the images in the debugger so I don't think I have a path problem.

Thank you very much for you help,

Cordially,
Matthieu Meunier

Comment: But what does your code output? Does an exception occur?

Comment: Nothing, no exception, or anything else. It just process till the save of the file and when I open it it display everything but the pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research with my colleagues we figured out that, in order to display a table , iText requires every column of a line to exist.

By that I mean, I tried to add in a "3 columned" table 2 images.

So, to avoid the table not displaying just add some empty cells like this :

```
PdfPCell whiteCell = new PdfPCell();
whiteCell.addElement(Chunk.NEWLINE);
photosTable.addCell(whiteCell);
```

Or more simply if you don't need any special cell formatting

```
photosTable.addCell(Chunk.NEWLINE);
```

I hope this will help some of you.

Regards,
Matthieu